# Evaluate $n^2 + (n-2)^2 + (n-4)^2 + (n-6)^2 + (n-8)^2 ...... (n-k)^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am preparing for my final exam in my University and I came across this kind of expression. Is there a way to evaluate this by Induction or any other means?

$$n^2 + (n-2)^2 + (n-4)^2 + (n-6)^2 + (n-8)^2 ...... (n-k)^2$$

I am having difficulty to figure out how to solve this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What you have there is not an equation. Do you mean $n^2+... (n-k)^2 =0$?

Comment: I am sorry! Yeah that is what I meant!! I can edit that, I just need to evaluate this.\

Comment: Before trying to solve for the roots of the expression, I would first try to simplify the expression.  Now... the expression doesn't make too much sense when $k$ is odd, so I'll make the assumption that $k$ is even and will call it $k=2j$ to make matters easier.  Add together each of the $n^2$ terms separately.  Then all of the $n$ terms.  Then all of the constants.  How many $n^2$ terms will there be?  $j+1$ of them.  How many $n$ terms will there be?  With what coefficients?  How do we go about adding $-4-8-12-16-\dots-4j$?

Comment: Hints: $\sum_{k=1}^n k = n(n+1)/2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$.

Comment: It might help to factor out a common factor of $-4$ from each to see it as $(-4)(1+2+3+4+\dots+j)$.  Now.. how about the constant terms... $4+16+36+\dots+4j^2$.  Maybe we can factor something out of this one as well...

Comment: I am solving for a recurrence relation in Algorithms and ended up with this expression. So it is going to go for value of n. Co-efficients are ignored, actually it doesn't matter.

Comment: This equation gives no real value of n.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{r=0}^m(n-2r)^2=n^2\sum_{r=0}^m1-4n\sum_{r=0}^mr+4\sum_{r=0}^mr^2$$

$$=n^2(m+1)-4n\cdot\dfrac{m(m+1)}2+4\cdot\dfrac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}6$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, that for every $k$ yoo obtain the quadratic equation:

$$n^2\cdot(k+1)-n\cdot2\sum_{z=0}^k(2z)+\sum_{z=0}^k(2z)^2=0$$
By evaluating these sums you obtain:
$$n^2\cdot(k+1)-n\cdot 2k(k+1) + \frac{2}{3}k(k+1)(2k+1)=0$$
You can divide both sides by $(k+1)$
$$n^2-2kn + \frac{2}{3}k(2k+1)=0$$
And from this point it should be easy to solve.

Comment: Do you know that $n^2 + (n-2)^2 + (n-4)^2 + (n-6)^2 + (n-8)^2 … (n-2k)^2$ will always be a positive number unless $n=k=0$.

Comment: @stevengregory And what about $n\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You should have mentioned that. Using $z$ instead of $n$ would have made it much more clear.